# How do I install packages? The usual generates a syntax error

Tags: python, import, pip, package, installation

I just wanted to get back to coding in Python using Jupyter notebook and have a very basic question/problem I couldn't find an answer for yet. I wanted to access World Bank's database such as described here: https://wbdata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ via

```
easy_install wbdata
```

or

```
pip install wbdata
```

and then proceeding by

`import wbdata as wb`

However I get this error

```
 File "<ipython-input-18-6de8bb5fe937>", line 4
    pip install wbdata
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also this 
`cd "The path to the python folder"`

as described here: [pip install returning invalid syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632891/pip-install-returning-invalid-syntax/56846027)
did not yield any results. 
Am I missing something? Do I need to install something before? I just freshly set it all up (Jupyter notebook via Anaconda with Python 3.7)
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you running that inside the jupyter notebook? Also, if you’re using Anaconda, be **very careful** about your use of pip.

Comment: Try reading this article about install packages in a jupyter notebook. https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError